# How to make visible atleast one line inside line chart even though the custom legend clicked to make invisible it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I created a line chart and i have 4 lines inside it.And 4 lines are of different colors.When clicking on the corresponding colored spots(inside custom legend)the corresponding colored lines will get disappear.And if again click the line will visible.If i made all lines invisible by clicking once in all colored spots, the entire chart will get disappear.                                                                Now i want at least one line to be visible even legend clicked.That is if only one line left in line chart don't allow it to disappear while clicking the legend                                        In my case  legend is not default from highchart.It is customized .Iam attatching code here

```js
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
  chart:{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    //polar: true,
    height: 600,
    type: 'line',
    //marginTop: 27 ,
    margin: [60, 10, 60, 10],
    events: {
      load: function() {

        // legend box
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'legend-box');
        document.getElementsByClassName('chart-indicator-ano')[0].appendChild(div);

        // items
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.setAttribute('class', 'item-list');
        div.appendChild(ul);
        
        this.series.forEach(function(s,i) { 
          var li = document.createElement('li'); 
          li.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item-' + (i + 1));
          li.style.opacity = 1;
          li.style.color = s.color;
          
          ul.appendChild(li);
          var sp = document.createElement('span'); 
          sp.setAttribute('class', 'hover-item-' + (i + 1));
          li.appendChild(sp);
            li.addEventListener('click', function() {
              this.setAttribute('data-open',"0");
             s.setVisible();
            
          });
        });

      }
    }
  },
  
  
  
  
  ...................
  ...................
  ...................
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will disable series hiding when there's only one visible series left:

```
// on custom legend item click
        var visibleSeries = 0,
          hidingEnabled = true;
        if (s.visible) {
          chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
            if (s.visible) {
              visibleSeries++;
            }
          });

          if (visibleSeries === 1) {
            hidingEnabled = false;
          }
        }

        if (hidingEnabled) {
          s.setVisible();
        }
```

Comment: I added the given code as shown here   :-                                                                                             
          li.addEventListener('click', function() {
            /*-----        your code here      ---*/  
           });                                                                                                                          But it not worked.Any way to SOLVE?

Comment: Please provide a live demo of this issue (jsfiddle preferably).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfp0gs0u/3/                                                                                       link with new code content added

Comment: Your code throws an error: `chart is not defined`. `chart` variable should be a reference to the chart object (which is `this` in the `chart.events.load` function).

Comment: How to solve it?can you please edit in given jsfiddle link

Comment: That issue solved.Created object for chart.And now i need a help,i want to change the order of the color of spots in custom legend.Now it is in cyan,green,red,white order.                                                                             
I want ** red,cyan,green,white** as order